# Full HD monitor resolution won't work even after adding xrandr mode

Tags: 20.04, display, display-resolution, monitor

I've been having trouble with my monitor resolution. Originally the maximum I could choose in the settings menu was 1024x768. After running `cvt 1920 1080`, `xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync` and `xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1920x1080_60.00"` the resolution menu began showing a 1920x1080 option.

After choosing it, the screen blinked once and it was back to 1024x768. I retried the commands with a 1600x900 resolution and it works fine, but now when I try to select 1920x1080 it just blinks and drops back to 1600x900.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 with kernel version 5.13.0-40-generic. My CPU is an Intel i7-4770 and I have no GPU, just Intel Graphics. My monitor is an AOC E2261Fw, which theoretically supports Full HD resolution. Here is my xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-1 connected primary 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900_60.00  59.95*+
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: is the problem possibly your VGA cable (assuming you're using VGA)? Theoretically VGA should be able to do 1080p but it depends on the cable quality.

Comment: Just changed cables and even though the image quality improved a little, the resolution still won't stay at 1920x1080. However, xrandr now shows 1600x900 as current resolution for ```Screen 0```

EDIT: After a reboot with the new cable the resolution started working again. Thank you so much! And sorry to have bothered you with such a silly problem